# Message error when trying to train a regression model using KNN method

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm currently taking an analytics class and i'm pretty much new to this. I'm trying to train a **regression model** using **KNN**, when I try set up the model using the **train** function, I keep receiving the following error message:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = gsub("^\\.", "", colnames(printed))) : attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

The code is:

```
TrControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                 number = 10,
                          repeats = 3)
modele <- train(outcome ~ .,
                 data = Train,
                 tuneGrid = expand_grid(k=1:70),
                 method = 'knn',
                 trControl = TrControl,
                 preProc = c('center','scale'))
```

If anybody can help that would be great :)

PS : The data used for the model is a dataframe with 23 variables and 2580 observations with column names as the first row and observations in the others.

Comment: What computer language is that code written in?

Comment: Please provide the head of the data as `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Did you try setting  the column names of you data frame to the first row (which contain the column names) and therefore removing the first row, before training your model. Something like: ```colnames(Train) <- Train[1,]``` and then
```Train <- Train[-1,]```